# Navigate between GridViews with keyboard arrows in Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have app layout with several GridViews, now the navigation between GridViews is done using TAB key, and you navigate inside each GridViews with arrows. What I would like to do, is: when I'm on the marginal element of one GridView, to press an arrow key to go to other GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is 100% possible, but requires 100% code. And if your grid item quantity is dynamic then the logic is that much more complex. But to your point, I know of apps that do this. Every one of them rolled their own solution to detect keyboard arrows and calc based on selected item in the grid.

It's why we are developers, right? Solving problems with code!

Best of luck!